# Get entire rolls using df.rolling()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have the following `df`:

```
      Price     Price2    Count  perc_change
0  0.000868    33782.17     4     1.000000
1  0.000872    33224.89     3     0.460829
2  0.000875    84110.85     7     0.344037
3  0.000878    67686.15     4     0.342857
4  0.000880    121400.22    4     0.227790
```

When using the following code:

```
def test(x):
    print(x)
    print("------")
    return x[1]

x = df.rolling(2, axis=0).apply(test)
```

I find myself with the following output:

```
[0.000868 0.000872]
------
[0.000872 0.000875]
------
[0.000875 0.000878]
------
[0.000878 0.00088 ]
------
[33782.17 33224.89]
------
[33224.89 84110.85]
------
[84110.85 67686.15]
------
[ 67686.15 121400.22]
------
[1.         0.46082949]
------
[0.46082949 0.3440367 ]
------
[0.3440367  0.34285714]
------
[0.34285714 0.22779043]
------
[4. 3.]
------
[3. 7.]
------
[7. 4.]
------
[4. 4.]
------
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is the following one:

```
[0.000868    33782.17     4     1.000000]
[0.000872    33224.89     3     0.460829]
------
[0.000875    84110.85     7     0.344037]
[0.000878    67686.15     4     0.342857]
[0.000880    121400.22    4     0.227790]
------
```

I've tried switching the `axis` argument to a `1` but it didn't work.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your end result is but this is one way to achieve your print out:

```
def test(x):
    print(df.loc[x])
    print("------")
    return x[1]

df.index.to_series().rolling(2).apply(test, raw=True)
```

Output:

```
        Price    Price2  Count  perc_change
0.0  0.000868  33782.17      4     1.000000
1.0  0.000872  33224.89      3     0.460829
------
        Price    Price2  Count  perc_change
1.0  0.000872  33224.89      3     0.460829
2.0  0.000875  84110.85      7     0.344037
------
        Price    Price2  Count  perc_change
2.0  0.000875  84110.85      7     0.344037
3.0  0.000878  67686.15      4     0.342857
------
        Price     Price2  Count  perc_change
3.0  0.000878   67686.15      4     0.342857
4.0  0.000880  121400.22      4     0.227790
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you very much for your answer, I'm trying to filter all rows by two and keep only the ones with the highest value in the `Count` column out of the two, and if the `Count` is the same then it will look at `Price2` and chose the highest one (so in my case `0.000868 `, `0.000875` and `0.000880` will be kept). I have already written 2 scripts to achieve this and all of them failed, do you think this approach with `rolling()` is the one you would recommend taking?

Comment: Hrm..... maybe...   Give it a try and see if you can get this to work the way you expect.

Comment: I get the following error when running the script, `TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'`

Comment: Older version of pandas.  Upgrade pandas.